# Can I use @@redux-form/INITIALIZE action?

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have a component whose virtual structure is something like this as shown below:

```
  <Header>
           My Status
     </Header>
      <Form>
        <Field.Text> Name: </Field.Text>
      </Form>
      <Footer>
        <a> foo link </a>
      </Footer>
```

So my header in the component , will contain either the status whether my form is saved or whether it encountered any errors while saving ?

My question is I looked into the source code of redux-form, during the initialization of the form , I have observed that 
`@@redux-form/INITIALIZE` action is dispatched.  When I reset this form, I want to clear all the text inside my header.

So is it a good practise , to directly catch the action 
`@@redux-form/INITIALIZE` or `@@redux-form/RESET` in my reducer to and set the text to null ? I am trying to ask this question , because in their documentation I could not find anything related to their usage of actions in the reducers.
If it is not a good practise, then would you happen to know what are disadvantages of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes based on some of the issues inside the redux-form github, and the amount of plus one received from the community, we can say with some certainty that it is normal to listen to the reduxform actions , and i believe that is one of the intended purpose of the HOC, is to lessen the amount of boilerplate action types that need to be defined for forms.

Based on this link https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2459 , we can say with certainty, that at some point the intention was to document the redux-form actionTypes.

Also based on this ,https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2178#issuecomment-283324287

I ended up importing the actions something like this in my reducer:

```
import { INIT, RESET } from 'redux-form/lib/actionTypes'

cont foo = (state = {}, action) => {
  case INIT:
     return {..state}
  case default:
     return state;
}
```

Note: Only do this(more likely advisable) , if you are not modifying the state of the form, but some other peer component, which is dependent on your formActions emitted.